# Can I amplify and listen to the RF frequencies in my body?

Tags: operational-amplifier, rf, antenna, frequency, radio

I have been interested in RF phenomena for while now.
I was wondering if it is possible to use the human body as an antenna, and came across these videos on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5RiN31uaTE&list=PLCr9p_qi3IOmh9g0RPiIK8p-6Xu3TqyhQ&index=60

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4Ji6EvhLB0&list=PLCr9p_qi3IOmh9g0RPiIK8p-6Xu3TqyhQ&index=58

These are just simple amplifier circuits, and I want to keep this simple, since I am still learning electronics.
I tried to recreate the "Amp-reciever" scenario, but was running into the problem that the headphone line started acting as an antenna.
Is there any way to fix this, or perhaps: is there a better way of doing this. I'm not necessarily interested in getting clear signals, but would find it interesting to listen to EMF and other near field frequencies as well. The image shows the schematic I've been working with. - from pin 3 I skipped the 10k pot, and ground connection, and wired a body contact, and I wired a 3.5mm jack socket instead of the speaker.
[image: LM386 Amp gain=50]

Looking forwards to hear back from you.
Many thanks
Martin

Comment: RF signals are not in the audible range: you can't hear (say) 100 MHz FM or 1 MHz AM directly. Also, the headphone wire is a much better antenna than your body.

Comment: This is a silly thing to do. Use an antenna to pick up RF signals and not your body. Making wiring connections to your body is just plain stupid given the risks and the ability to use a normal antenna. Voting to close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a pointless and dangerous exercise.

Comment: Those videos are a pain to watch and they explain nothing. The schematic is just a generic low-quality audio amplifier that picks up stray AM transmissions. It's not a radio receiver.

Comment: Andy aka: How is it dangerous? I was under the impression that I would just be amplifying the frequencies that are anyways being picked up by my body.

Comment: I think I need to make it clear that I'm not trying to build a radio here. I am interested in whether or not it is possible to listen to the frequencies that are being picked up in our bodys.

Comment: Yes Martin, Telepathy has to use RF, likely Subhz, still RF, meaning no wire , rhyme with Subconsciousness, You need large "tank circuitry" around head (the Antenna). Loo at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPbtR4vorgY)

Comment: "I am interested in whether or not it is possible to listen to the frequencies that are being picked up in our bodys".  That's the definition of a radio.  "I'm not trying to build a radio here."  Oh yes you are.  You listened to someone's word-salad and you mistook it for sensible talking.  For the purposes of picking up electromagnetic signals ("frequencies" in your word salad), we are ugly bags of mostly water.  Salty water.  Make a human-shaped tank as big as you, fill it with your weight of salty water, and you have -- functionally -- the same thing as you.

Comment: @TimWescott Yes, another great idea! It is possible through modulation and mapping process.

Answer (score 1):

Body as antenna?   Or are you after the signals *originating* in your body?

For the latter, you'll be finding muscle signals, heartbeat, and brain-waves.  EMG, EKG, and EEG.   Your amplifier gain is minimal, but you might be able to hear the white-noise "roar" inside your arm whenever you clench your fist.  Need high-gain preamp, at least one stage of op-amp.  (The diff-amp input will also greatly help to eliminate 60Hz and other external noise.)

SAFETY HAZARD!!  Always use battery power for body-connected devices.  If you used wall-transformers or other AC power supply, there's a chance that, for a malfunction, YOU MAY DIE.

Comment: I want to make a handheld battery powered device, that allows me to listen to different frequencies our body's pick up. -in this case I guess the body acts as a kind of antenna.

Comment: @Martin Then you're making a radio, and using yourself as an antenna.

Comment: And why exactly would this be dangerous, if it's run on batteries?